# How to know if the bounding box is inside another bounding box?

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, yolo

I am trying to get the head-body ratio of the person detected. In order to do that I have to determine if the head detected is completely inside the body detected. I am struggling specially if more than 1 person is detected. I tried the xmin1xmin2 and ymin1ymin2 but there is still some glitch. Can anyone help me?
[image: example]

Comment: Please show your code and explain what the glitch exactly is.

Comment: You can pass the head and body bounding box into an IoU function. If it returns 1, that means the head is entirely inside the body bounding box

Comment: @GoodDeeds The glitch is when after I compare the head and body coordinates using the isoverlapping function(a[0] < b[2] and a[2] > b[0]) and (a[1] < b[3] and a[3] > b[1]) there are two body and 1 head that satisfies the given condition(isoverlapping function) so it cause confusion.  So I wanted to know if there is another way to identify if a bbox is completely inside another bbox

Comment: @amisotcm I'll try the iou one. Thank youuu

Comment: [mre] is required. take the [tour] and review [ask].